# Why is Android Studio able to execute some Git commands, but the UI throws an NPE trying to do a merge?

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio, github

I was able to use the Android Studio IDE to pull the project from the repository, add changed files, commit them, view status/logs. But when I try to push back to the same remote repo (master branch, the only on yet there), I get error message like this:

> 6:31:30 PM Couldn't save uncommitted changes.
>              Tried to save uncommitted changes in stash before Update, but failed with an error.
>              stash file://C:/Users/mejohnsn/AndroidStudioProjects/SylloGizmo: fatal:
>   'stash' appears to be a git command, but we were not 6:31:31 PM
>   NullPointerException: null

It looks like it is trying to say that 'stash' looks like a legitimate git command, but it could not actually find it. Not that I understand where it is finding uncommitted changes or why it ignores .gitignore, but these are probably side issues.

I also get a Toast like popup offering to report the IDE bug to Google, which I finally did. I can't include that, because it disappears too quickly, I can't remember the wording.
But the real problem is that in the meantime, I need a workaround. Should I try rebase instead of merge? Is there something incomplete about the AS Git integration when running under Windows w/o Cygwin?

> System info: Windows 10, AS ver. 2.2.3, JRE: 1.0.0_76-release-b03
>   amd64 (why amd? This is an Intel machine) JVM OpenJDK 64-Bit Server by
>   JetBrains.

Comment: A workaround for an IDE's GIT integration not working is to run the git commands from the command line, or using a separate Git gui tool.  For Windows consider using "gitbash".

Comment: Open the version control tab in Android Studio locate the internal console tab. Repeat the actions above and copy the output to your question. Select the Event log  copy the output to your question. I hope this will help us to better under stand your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SourceTree does look like one of the better GUIs, but it was still confusing to try to figure out what the color coding meant and what branch it was trying to merge with what when clicking on 'merge'. But I did a pull and a merge from the GUI, then, disappointed by the GUI output, switched back to the command line (using SourceTree's 'Terminal') and did the push from there. Now the output of command line git status makes sense, and I see pretty much what I expect through Github's web interface. Yes, there are two commits instead of one, but as long as the latest is correct (and it is), I don't care.

Oh: and instead of New Repo > Add Existing Local Repo", I did File>Open and found the desired local repo on my system. That seemed to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it is better to use dedicated UI Git client as they are much more feature rich and easier to use. I recommendto give SourceTree a try, since UI based client lets you see clearly the commit/branch/merge lines.

Comment: I downloaded SourceTree. It seems to want me to clone a repository before I can do anything with it. But what I need now is for SourceTree to "take over" a repo for which I already have the working copy on my system and I see no way to do this using their GUI. Fortunately, they do offer a Terminal, which looks like a pretty thorough emulation of bash in the Windows environment. I will probably try that instead.

Comment: In the main SouceTree window. + New Repository > Add Existing Local Repository > Find your folder

This will add the existing folder you have into SourceTree. Hope this helps